# Autocomplete filtered with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, autocomplete, mongodb-atlas-search

I would like to perform autocompletion on the **name** but filtered on a specific city with mongoose and nodejs.
I have a mongodb collection like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6007fd9d984e2507ad452cf3"),
    "name" : "John",
    "city" : "A",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6007ff6844d9e517e1ec0976"),
    "name" : "Jack",
    "city" : "B",
}
```

**What i have done so far :**

I have setup MongoDB Atlas with a Search Index (with the help of [search doc](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/))
And set up the autocomplete like that :

```
router.get('/search', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    let result = await Client.aggregate([
      {
        "$search": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "query": `${request.query.term}`,
            "path": "name",
            "fuzzy": {
              "maxEdits": 2,
              "prefixLength": 3,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $limit: 3
      },
      {
        $project: {
          "_id": 0,
        }
      }
    ]);
    response.send(result);
  } catch (e) {
    response.status(500).send({message: e.message});
  }
});
```

In front-end, with [autocompleteJs](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/) :

```
  const autoCompleteJS = new autoComplete({
    data: {
      src: async () => {
        const query = document.querySelector("#autoComplete").value;
        const source = await fetch(`${window.location.origin}/search?term=${query}`);
        const data = await source.json();
        return data;
      },
      key: ["name"],
    },
    trigger: {
      event: ["input", "focus"],
    },
    searchEngine: "strict",
    highlight: true,
  });
```

So far it is working well. But I don't know how to make the autocomplete result filtered based on city. It seems that the [documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/#std-label-autocomplete-ref) does not mention this. Do you have any leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$where` pipeline stage from the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) after performing your search to filter out unwanted documents. So for example,

```
Client.aggregate([
  {
    "$search": {
      "autocomplete": {
        "query": `${request.query.term}`,
        "path": "name",
        "fuzzy": {
          "maxEdits": 2,
          "prefixLength": 3,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  { 
    $match: { city: 'city-name' } 
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul ! Working very well with $match :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [compound](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/) operator like so which lets you have more control over your results in a performant fashion:

```
"$search": {
  "compound" : {
    "filter" : [{ 
       "text" : { path: "city", query: "New York" } 
     }],
     "must": [{ 
          "autocomplete": {
            "query": `${request.query.term}`,
            "path": "name",
            "fuzzy": {
              "maxEdits": 2,
              "prefixLength": 3,
            },
          },}
        }] }
```

using `filter` will filter your results, without impacting the score.  `must` will require that the `name` field will also match.   Also take a look at `should` and `mustNot` in the `compound` docs for more options.

Comment: Thank you Doug ! But unfortunately, I don't know why – with the "filter". The result returns me an empty Array :/ (perhaps filter is incompatible with autocomplete ?)

Comment: I have the same issue @Doug, do we need to add an index on the filter path?