# Mongo Go driver search autocomplete with compound operator

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to do a search autocomplete with respect to another field in the object using Go Mongo driver.
This is what I have

```golang
filter := bson.A{
  bson.M{
    "$search": bson.M{
      "compound": bson.M{
        "filter": bson.M{"city": cityName},
          "must": bson.M{
            "autocomplete": bson.M{
              "query":      searchQuery,
              "path":       "email",
              "tokenOrder": "any",
            },
          },
      },
    },
  },
}

cur, err := someCollection.Aggregate(ctx, filter)
```

Honestly, I am not very sure sure this is the correct approach. I am just trying to find email addresses while making sure they belong to a particular `cityName`. From other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078980/autocomplete-filtered-with-mongodb) I found that I need to use compound but I am not really sure how. The above code results in the error
`"(UnknownError) Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: \"filter\" one of [autocomplete, compound, equals, exists, geoShape, geoWithin, near, phrase, queryString, range, regex, search, span, term, text, wildcard] must be present (from \"compound\")"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the accepted answer from the link in the question and set up the filter as

```
filter := bson.A{
        bson.M{
            "$search": bson.M{
                "autocomplete": bson.M{
                    "query":      searchQuery,
                    "path":       "email",
                    "tokenOrder": "any",
                },
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{"city": cityName},
        },
        bson.M{
            "$limit": 5,
        },
    }
```

It works but my original attempt with compounds is supposed to be performant (at least that is what the other answer says in the link)

Answer (score 0):

In the compound pipeline multiple conditions are joined in single query for improving query performance, single operators can have multiple conditions for that it is required in array format (`bson.A`) which is missing within operators within pipeline.

```
filter := bson.A{
  bson.M{
    "$search": bson.M{
      "compound": bson.M{
        "must": bson.A{
          bson.M{
            "autocomplete": bson.M{
              "query":      searchQuery,
              "path":       "email",
              "tokenOrder": "any",
            },
          },
        },
        "filter": bson.A{
          bson.M{
            "text": bson.M{
              "query": cityName,
              "path": "city",
            },
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

cur, err := someCollection.Aggregate(ctx, filter)
```

Comment: Thank you but this only returns an empty list

Comment: @zer0 have you created indexes for search.

Comment: Yes, search indexes exist

Comment: @zer0 try moving filter after autocomplete and also what happens if you remove the filter.