# Search MongoDB autocomplete filtered

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, atlas

I want to search autocomplete on the following fields :contactfirstname, contactlastname and name

Also, want to filter based on userid(s) first then perform autocomplete search

Issue:
Without filter criteria, autocomplete is working fine
With filter criteria in compound query not working as getting empty array

Can anyone help please?

```
exports.userNameCitySearchAutocomplete = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const { userNameCityQueryparam } = req.query;
    console.log("search query param", userNameCityQueryparam);
    const agg = [
      {
        $search: {
            index: 'userNameCity',
            'compound': {
              
              "filter": [{
               "text": {
                  "query": ["6271f2bb79cd80194c81f631"],
                  "path": "_id",
                }
              }],

            "should": [
              {
              //search on user name
      
              autocomplete: {
                query: userNameCityQueryparam,
                path: 'name',
                fuzzy: {
                  maxEdits: 2,
                  prefixLength: 3
                }
              }},

              //search on user city
            
              {
                autocomplete: {
                query: userNameCityQueryparam,
                path: 'city',
                fuzzy: {
                  maxEdits: 2,
                  prefixLength: 3
                }
              },
           }
           ,

              //search on user contact first name
            
              {
                autocomplete: {
                query: userNameCityQueryparam,
                path: 'contactfirstname',
                fuzzy: {
                  maxEdits: 2,
                  prefixLength: 3
                }
              },
           }

           ,

              //search on user contact last name
            
              {
                autocomplete: {
                query: userNameCityQueryparam,
                path: 'contactlastname',
                fuzzy: {
                  maxEdits: 2,
                  prefixLength: 3
                }
              },
           }
           
          ],
            "minimumShouldMatch": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    const response = await User.aggregate(agg);
    return res.json(response);
    // res.send(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("autocomplete search error", error);
    return res.json([]);
  }
};
```

**Index details in mongodb:**
[image]

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "contactfirstname": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "contactlastname": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Image of collection in mongodb
[image]

image of empty array
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking for solution to this,
You can use the MQL where clause in your pipeline stage definition.

```
{
    $match: {
      email:"email@domain.com"
    }
}
```

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078980/autocomplete-filtered-with-mongodb) for an example

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mongo atlas search would be use:

```js
db.professionList.aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      index: "default",
      compound: {
        should:[
          { 
            autocomplete: {
              query: "tax",
              path:"keywords" ,
              tokenOrder:"sequential"
            }
          },
          {
            autocomplete: {
              query: "tax",
              path:"name" ,
              tokenOrder:"sequential"
            }
          }
        ],
        minimumShouldMatch: 0 
      }
    }
  },
  { $limit:10 },
  {
    $project:{
        _id:0,
        name:1,
        keywords:1,
    }
  }
])
```

`compound` and `should` are the labels to help to use more fields in autocomplete search